# arara: How to conditionally compile the document if changes took place to any file in a subdirectory?

Tags: arara

Suppose I have some `*.tex` files in a subdirectory named `SourceFiles`, how can I make arara compile the document if and only if there are changes to any tex file in this subdirectory?

I tried

```
% arara: lualatex if changed (toFile(
% arara: --> listFilesByExtensions( toFile('/SourceFiles'), [ 'tex' ], false)
% arara: --> ))
```

but I got this error

> [Error: null pointer or function not found: listFilesByExtensions]
>   [Near : {... || changed (toFile( listFilesByExtensions( toFile( ....}]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that's correct: `listFilesByExtensions` is not available in the directive context, only inside the rule scope. Besides, there would be another issue if the evaluation managed to reach the outer function call: `changed` only supports a single file at a time, not  a list of files.

The typical solution, in your specific scenario, would be writing a proper rule. The team is discussing, for future versions, a functional route as a means to allow advanced constructs such as `all`, `any` and `none` in the directive scope.

This is the official response from the team. `:)`

That said...

## HIC SUNT DRACONES

Also...

### *Lasciate ogne speranza, voi ch'intrate*

There is a very hacky way to achieve what you want. I will exploit the expression language and trigger the function call through a full qualified name. This is not recommended at all and should be avoid at all costs. I think we ducks like challenges. `:)`

This header should work for you.

```
% arara: lualatex if
% arara: --> entries = 
% arara: --> com.github.cereda.arara.utils.Methods.listFilesByExtensions(
% arara: --> toFile('SourceFiles/'), ['tex'], false
% arara: --> );
% arara: --> flag = false;
% arara: --> foreach(entry : entries) {
% arara: -->   flag = changed(entry) || flag;
% arara: --> };
% arara: --> return flag
```

A few notes about this header:

```
% arara: lualatex if
```

Nothing new here, `arara` will run the engine if, and only if, the following expression holds true.

```
% arara: --> entries = 
% arara: --> com.github.cereda.arara.utils.Methods.listFilesByExtensions(
```

Now things get different: for starters, I call `listFilesByExtensions` by using the full qualified name in the expression language. The return value of this function is then saved in a variable named `entries`.

```
% arara: --> toFile('SourceFiles/'), ['tex'], false
% arara: --> );
```

These are the arguments: the directory (I removed the `/` in the beginning, as it would be resolved to a full path starting from root, and I believe that would not be what you want, and added a trailing `/` just to satisfy my coding OCD), a list of extensions (in this case, we are looking for `.tex` files) and a boolean value indicating whether the search should be recursive (in our case, no).

```
% arara: --> flag = false;
```

I created a boolean variable named `flag`, originally set to `false`, which will hold the indication whether any file resulted from the previous search has changed.

```
% arara: --> foreach(entry : entries) {
% arara: -->   flag = changed(entry) || flag;
% arara: --> };
```

This is now a loop to inspect each and every file resulted from the previous search. Observed that `changed` is in the left side of the `||` operation. This is not a cosmetic option, it has a deeper meaning: if I put `changed` on the right side, short-circuiting might save a call in case `flag` holds `true` and thus the file database won't be updated anymore from that iteraction on.

```
% arara: --> return flag
```

Now, `flag` indicates if any of the files have changed, so the compilation will be based on that decision. Since it's the last statement in the expression, it would be returned regardless, but I like to keep things more explicit and more verbose and more complicated because we ducks like complicated things. `:)`

That's it, basically. Congratulations, you've voided the warranty! `:)`

Hope it helps! `:)`

---

*Addendum:* The headers shown in the comments have at least two problems: first is related to syntax, second is related to semantics. The second header works by coincidence because short-circuiting will cause certain files to not having their statuses updated. This would be a possible fix to both headers:

#### Header 1

```
% arara: lualatex: { options: [ '-synctex=1',
% arara: --> '-shell-escape','-interaction=nonstopmode' ]} 
% arara: --> if 
% arara: --> flag = changed(currentFile());
% arara: --> entries = 
% arara: --> com.github.cereda.arara.utils.Methods.listFilesByExtensions(
% arara: --> toFile('SourceFiles/'), ['tex'], false
% arara: --> );
% arara: --> foreach(entry : entries) {
% arara: -->   flag = changed(entry) || flag;
% arara: --> };
% arara: --> flag = missing('log') || flag;
% arara: --> flag = missing('aux') || flag;
% arara: --> flag = (exists('log') && found ('log','(Undefined control sequence|Error)')) || flag;
% arara: --> return flag
```

#### Header 2

```
% arara: lualatex: { options: [ '-synctex=1',
% arara: --> '-shell-escape','-interaction=nonstopmode' ]} 
% arara: --> if
% arara: --> entries = 
% arara: --> com.github.cereda.arara.utils.Methods.listFilesByExtensions(
% arara: --> toFile('SourceFiles/'), ['tex'], false
% arara: --> ); flag = false;
% arara: --> foreach(entry : entries) {
% arara: -->   flag = changed(entry) || flag;
% arara: --> };
% arara: --> flag = changed(currentFile()) || flag;
% arara: --> flag = missing('log') || flag;
% arara: --> flag = missing('aux') || flag;
% arara: --> flag = (exists('log') && found ('log','(Undefined control sequence|Error)')) || flag;
% arara: --> return flag
```

Since the syntax exploits the workings of the expression language mechanism, it requires a certain level of programming and tweaking in order to function properly. That's why I consider it a hacky way to achieve the desired behaviour.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer; unfortunately, I am away from PC to experiment. However, I have two inquiries: 1- do you imply that this code won't work without internet access since it needs to call this function from your webpage? 2- is there a way to tweak any current rule? If not, would you please propose a rule that can handle this functionality offline if your answer needs an internet connection?

Comment: 1. No, it's not an internet address, it is something similar to a function address, it relates to the internal packaging structure. So no worries. :) 2. Tweak in which sense?

Comment: I mean is there an existing rule that can be edited in some way to achieve this? If not, I would be grateful if you could provide a complete rule for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't follow. What exactly do you want a rule to achieve?

Comment: I think I didn't say it properly enough since I need to experiment first before commenting :) I appreciate your help and will get back in case I get lost.

Comment: No worries, feel free to poke me any time you need. `:)`

Comment: I wanted to check for changes in the main file and those in the subdirectory. So, my approach was [this one](https://pastebin.com/CRqe8JSn). However, I got an error `String index out of range: -1`. Contrarily, if I make the checking for changes in the main file after those in the subfolder as [here](https://pastebin.com/b9hRZqEq), it works fine. May I know why, and how to make the first one work? Thanks

Comment: I can spot two problems with your two headers: first is related to syntax, second is related to semantics. The second works by coincidence because short-circuiting will cause certain files to not having their statuses updated. I will see what I can do in this answer...

Comment: Out of curiosity: is `flag` a predefined internal boolean variable or just a defined boolean variable that can take any name?

Comment: It is a user-defined variable which could assume any name, just like `entries` and `entry` in the header. `:)`